Http request getting blocked when app deployed on Netlify
I have the application working on my localhost and the API call is working just fine when I submit the email, but when I deployed the app on Netlify I get the following
Error:
stunning-daifuku-2134a0.netlify.app/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stunning-daifuku-2134a0.netlify.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://34.225.132.160:8002/api'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
The API I'm using is: "http://34.225.132.160:8002/api/"
Github:Github
Deployed app: app
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ContactMe = () => {
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState("")
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://34.225.132.160:8002/api/",
        {email: email}
      );
      setIsError("");
      setSuccessMessage(response.data.message);
      setTimeout(()=>{
        setSuccessMessage("");
        setEmail("");
      },3000)

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("err->", error.message);
      setIsError(error.message);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="contact__me__container">
      {isError ? (<p className="error__message">{isError}</p>) : successMessage? (
        <p className="success__message">{successMessage}</p>
      ): ""}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="contact__me__body">
        <input
          required
          type="text"
          className="input__field"
          value={email}
          placeholder="Email Address"
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="submit__btn" disabled={isLoading}>
          {isLoading ? <img className="spinner_green" src="spinner_green.svg" alt="loading" /> : "Contact Me"}
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContactMe;

I have tried adding "/* http://34.225.132.160:8002/api/:splat 200" to the _redirects file in a public folder but the issue still persists.

Try this solution Link

I added the meta tag in the header "" this doesn't work. Adding / at the end of the URL doesn't work

Your react application which is deployed at Netlify has served over HTTPS, and your submit event is trying to reach the HTTP endpoint which is not secured. That's why you are getting a mix-content error. Make sure to deploy both over HTTPS.

Yes that much I understand, but the API is given to me for a project, I didn't create the API. Is there a solution to it?
